# How to check orderbychild value exist?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I successfully get the username by searching the subject which is saved under username in the tlocation. But what if the subject totally not exist under all username so how I am gonna detect whether the subject exist in the tlocation? If you got any idea please share it to me thank you.

here's my code

```
tref.orderByChild("subject").equalTo(ssubject).
addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
 //ssubject is user selected subject
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    for (final DataSnapshot u: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        if(u.child("subject").getValue().equals(ssubject)){

        // do some code here 

        }else{

          searchuserlist.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.stv));

        }
```

here's my database structure
[image]

Comment: Please edit your question and make it clear.

Comment: @Supradip.M Sorry. I'm also get confused to explain in detail.

Comment: From what I understood, you have 2 options : - Add the subjects to the list that you're displaying, so that only present subjects are shown. - Secondly, just check if the subject at particular query has a value else it will return null and you can take it from there.

Comment: I found out one syntax very helpful and it solved my problem but can you explain to me about this dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().hasNext()? @Supradip.M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can verify if the `subject` exists:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference userRef = rootRef.child("tlocation").child("rexyou0831");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.child("subject").exists()) {
            //do something
        } else {
            //do something else
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
userRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

I have used `rexyou0831` as an example. Instead of `rexyou0831` you can use the `userName` variable.